# Turn for loop of Axios post requests to promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, axios

I have a loop of axios requests:

```
for(const [number, response] of Object.entries(questions)){
  axios.post(
    this.address+'surveypost',
     {"patientID": patientID,
              "questionID": number,
                "likertResponse": response,
                  "surveyNumber": surveyID, "admin": this.admin, "masterpassword": this.masterpassword},
    { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} }
  )
    .then(e =>{console.log(e);
    console.log("inserted")})
    .catch(error =>{console.log(error)})
}
```

and I need to turn them into one axios promise. How would I go about that so that I can return a promise, that makes sure all have completed?

my desired output is `return promise(...)`  or something similar, as there are things that I have to do do subsequent actions like this in:

`var chain = Promise.resolve()
      .then(promise) // LOOPED AXIOS POST REQUEST ABOVE 
      .then(another_promise) // subsequent actions;`

Comment: use Promise.all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can push each promise to an array and call `Promise.all`

```
let promsArr = [];
for(const [number, response] of Object.entries(questions)){
  promsArr.push(axios.post(
    this.address+'surveypost',
     {"patientID": patientID,
              "questionID": number,
                "likertResponse": response,
                  "surveyNumber": surveyID, "admin": this.admin, "masterpassword": this.masterpassword},
    { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} }
  ))
}

Promise.all(promsArr)
.then(resp => {
  console.log("data", resp);
})
.catch(err => {console.log(err)})
```